# Uncaught Type Error when using Titanium Alloy models

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I am using Titanium alloy models, most of the code I extracted from sample

https://github.com/appcelerator/alloy/tree/master/samples/todo

When I tried to compile my project I got this error.

[image]

I am using Titanium 3.1.2, Alloy 1.2.2

Comment: So are you running the exact code you just posted?  Or something different. If you changed *anything* show the code.

Comment: Had figured out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had figured out the issue. I had not added the `collection` in the markup.

Adding `<Collection src="note"/>` as first child of `alloy` solved the issue.